# Returning a promise from a function in ArcGIS API JavaScript version 4.x

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

How would I return a promise from a queryTask from a function in ArcGIS API version 4.x?

```
function getPromise() {
  require(["esri/tasks/support/Query", "esri/tasks/QueryTask"], function (Query, QueryTask) {
    var query = new Query...
    var queryTask = new QueryTask....
    return queryTask.execute(query)
  });
}

getPromise().then(function(response) {
    .......
    // getPromise() returns undefined here
})
```

the above would cause an error :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

I noticed that if I place the require.... outside of the getPromise function, then the promise returns fine. However, when the require... is placed inside the function, it causes the error.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a `QueryTask` is not an asynchronous operation, so does not return a Promise. I think you're looking for [queryTask.execute()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-QueryTask.html#execute), which, as you can see in the documentation, does return a promise.

```
function getPromise() {
  var query = new Query();
  var queryTask = new QueryTask( ... );
  query.where = "STATE_NAME = 'Washington'";
  query.outSpatialReference = { wkid:102100 };
  query.returnGeometry = true;
  query.outFields = [ "CITY_NAME" ];
  return queryTask.execute(query);
}

getPromise().then(function(response) {
    .......
})
```

Comment: Hi GavinR. You're right, I meant to write queryTask.execute() which in fact does return a promise. I re-edited my question. I hope to require the Query and QueryTask inside the getPromise function. Doing it that way does not return the promise. Do you have any insight? Thank you.